# dovecot - changing inbox folder or move inbox mail for one user

Tags: email-server, cron, dovecot

I am trying to change where dovecot places new incoming emails from the inbox, to another folder, which i've named PreInbox OR I'd like to move all emails from inbox to PreInbox via cron or something.
when running `doveadm mailbox list -u ###@###.com` dovecot shows the folder as:
INBOX
INBOX.PreInbox
INBOX.Archive
etc...
I know that I can change the inbox namespace in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` but this would change the setting for all mail accounts and I want to do this for only **ONE** user. Is there a way to set a configuration file for a single user?
Alternatively, moving the emails using cron: I've tried moving the emails from the directory that holds inbox emails to the directory for .PreInbox as such: `mv mail/user/cur/*emailfile* mail/user/.PreInbox/cur/` when checking the mail, it disappears from the inbox but does not show in the PreInbox folder, when moved back to the original directory it shows in the inbox again.
I am not a dovecot master, so I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for [mail location](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/) and [configuration](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/config_file/config_variables/#conditionals), you can use something like

```
mail_location = maildir:~/mail:INBOX=%{if;%u;eq;name;Preinbox;INBOX}
```

where `name` is the name of the user you want to treat differently. This needs version 2.2.33 or later for the conditional.

Comment: it appears that where, in the conditional statement, you have PreInbox and INBOX, literal, dynamic paths may be required? when looking at dovecot.conf, the examples look like ```#   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n``` do you see how INBOX= leads to a literal, dynamic path? would you concur with this conclusion? though it does get confusing, because i'm not using mbox files, and the example for maildir looks like ```#   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir```

Comment: Not sure. I think you'll just have to try it.